# Laravel: how to use fields to display in blade?

Tags: laravel

I have `{{collect($consumer->orders)->sortByDesc('created_at')->first()`, which returns an object but I need to display the `ordered_date` from that object.

Right now in my blade file, I have:
`<span> {{collect($consumer->orders)->sortByDesc('created_at')->first() </span>` but that is printing the ENTIRE object when I really only want the field on the object.

Comment: So add `->the_name_of_the_field_you_want` after the `->first()`?

Answer (score 0):

The code is not working because `first()` method return single object. That's why you are getting the entire object.

You can achieve this as below:

`<span> {{collect($consumer->orders)->sortByDesc('created_at')->first()->ordered_date </span>`